# Select-XML does nothing when using namespace

Tags: xml, powershell

There are some code

123.xml:

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP:Body>
    <P2MessageServiceStatus>
      <CONNECTION>CONNECTION_CONNECTED</CONNECTION>
      <ROUTER>ROUTER_CONNECTED</ROUTER>
    </P2MessageServiceStatus>
  </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

so, i am trying go get value using name Spaces. It runs ok without it, but with namespaces it does nothing

```
$url='http://123.xml'
$xpath='/SOAP:Envelope/SOAP:Body/P2MessageServiceStatus/@CONNECTION'
$namespace='SOAP'

$wc = New-Object  Net.WebClient
[xml]$xml_body = $wc.DownloadString($url)
$xmlvalue= Select-Xml -XPath $xpath -Xml $xml_body -Namespace @{ SOAP = 'http://test'}
```

$xmlvalue will be empty with no errors, how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things wrong here:

1. Namespace is not right
2. Connection is not an attribute, so `@` is not necessary.

This worked for me:

```
$xml = [xml] (gc e:\1.txt )
$xpath='/SOAP:Envelope/SOAP:Body/P2MessageServiceStatus/CONNECTION'
$xmlvalue= Select-Xml -XPath $xpath -Xml $xml -Namespace @{ "SOAP" = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'}
$xmlvalue
```

Comment: It works for me for XML from the question. If you have different XML - please post it